# Import openssl public key to C# RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, pem, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am create server side program in c++, program create RSA public and private key with openssl library and then public key distribute over the network for clients. in clients side i wrote c# program first get public key and then encrypt data. but i can not add public key to  RSACryptoServiceProvider.

is there a way to import RSA public key to RSACryptoServiceProvider?

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCAKCAQEAsgVkBAQPdtRtICOqWdZ0ZiMAb9UvUX0BaxANN22bL5RzTJAL+PmG
QKaA61B1m0NPOjdIIXMwkaAzXOmzuNwKm2Ugb8jO15B6ovAhe73jAoltFFdi10Te
zCJgT8/xLAWt1mOXCAK9vD4Pv5LMN76BF+YjEVvylQ3l87255ElZrP4UluCGj0U3
uczW8+Cqao3QoL6xSxPU9jSK0FT/OhAL312cAXYbnaiJH+wAf1kkv4ez28XAlFId
MlCmh2n8YSuxk1GdOXaps8IoluDzmHeQ8vk2quQMPpFXzfCayBoPm9lVPOjOQkAH
8ClJda0Uy052N5aE0BuyX1KRxOSdRRKk9wIBAw==

-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: Does this project help: https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), which is, unfortunately, one of the only ways to solve this problem.

```
PemReader reader = new PemReader(new StreamReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)reader.ReadObject();
reader.Reader.Close();
```

This code isn't tested, so some of the method names might be a tad off.  You can then use the static methods in the `DotNetUtilities` class to convert to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code show how to add RSA public key to RSACryptoServiceProvider in c#

```
public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
     writer.Write(s);
     writer.Flush();
     stream.Position = 0;
     return stream;
}

string publicKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCAKCAQEAoNhWLaL11Zy4L6Cp2IDFv2JGnPkoRnFrKTy5b23uszzbSammdIwi\n6Wtr/7Zg3wmqlwt/yhH4F6rwSysB04xvMnWjuRsw2Kz4u7FHMPlgrIObGDFqcEms\nllNTA8xSWh/+TPfxWdAN5bpUwLYo6Mizl+VStL4CtVQFS8/mQSUnCju3csfxNGlk\nPQdbwZWB/5DdswrhkUcob8wl3bCCZCz3zWzMNJFTgTEiZQr+qTtuY7ST+fmpO33r\nDJoboysiGPKUkQixKcG2s1jJJkQircAHkmiQPS6PlUapNahFNaPa3rh1zR4l5NN6\nxWudPYQhZ8VvD4C8eT2bfrUlsikAyXIX4QIBAw==\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
using (Stream stream = GenerateStreamFromString(publicKey))
{

      PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StreamReader(stream));
      AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
      pemReader.Reader.Close();
      Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters rsaPub = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters)publicKey;

      RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rsaPub);

      RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
      RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

      byte[] encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(plainText, true);
}
```